# How to run function in background with service worker

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I am building a javascript Web Application. In there i want to upload pictures and other data to a server. This is all working, but i want to use the application offline as well. Therefore i implemented the indexedDB, to store the data offline. Furthermore i made a sync-function, which will be executed every 5 seconds (setIntervall()...) to syncronise the data to the server if there is a internet connection again.

The problem is, that this sync-function only works when the app is open. So I researched a method to solve my problem and i got the idea of a "service worker" with background sync.

The problem is i don't know how to implement it.

This is what i currently have (the whole app is programmed in MVC-concept):

- I have a sw.js with the following code:

```
  if (event.tag == 'myFirstSync') {
    event.waitUntil(sync());
  }
});
```

- In the controller there is the function sync() for synchronising the data

Comment: Can you clarify a little bit :-) What do you mean when you say "I don't know how to implement it"? Be sure to check out these resources: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/12/background-sync https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/

Comment: yes i read all this stuff but i found no exact documentation how to implementent such background execution of a function :(

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your background sync inside of your `sw.js` file, in the handler for the 'sync' event:

```
self.addEventListener('sync', function(event) {
  if (event.tag == 'myFirstSync') {
    event.waitUntil(() => {
      // Put your sync code here.
    });
  }
});
```

At some point after you register your service worker, you need to trigger a sync:

```
// Register your service worker:
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js');

// Then later, request a one-off sync:
navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(swRegistration) {
  return swRegistration.sync.register('myFirstSync');
});
```

After triggering the sync once, if it fails, the sync should keep on retrying on its own (even if the app is not open in the browser).

> If it fails, another sync will be scheduled to retry. Retry syncs also
>   wait for connectivity, and employ an exponential back-off.

See https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/12/background-sync for further details.

Comment: no this is not working for me, i wrote this code in my sw.js file, i can see the ServiceWorker in the dev-tools of chrome, but he didn't execute the code after waitUntil()... is there anything missing?

Comment: do i have to put the second code into the controller or in sw.js?

Comment: @90minutes2go - in the sw.js file. You cannot execute/call any functions from any other places in your codebase. Service Worker has its own execution context as does the normal browser page. Your page doesn't see functions and variables defined inside the SW.js and vice versa.

Comment: @90minutes2go the first snippet goes in the service worker. The second snippet goes in the application code, its purpose is to register the service worker and register your sync event.